# How to make Linux stop eating power?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I recently switched to Linux (Ubuntu), and I noticed that my cooler(in laptop) is always on. I didn't have my cooler always turned on(or I didn't notice), when I was using Windows. Is there anything I can do or it should be like this?

Answer (score -2):

I searched on Web for more information, and got this answer:
Hardware Drivers are developed specifically for a Windows or MacOS in 99% time. So drivers are not designed for a Linux. Because, get this, less than 1% of all computer and other devices use Linux. So the performance of hardware is decreased and be ready to always hearing your fan spinning.